# Is there a way to subscribe to IIs application pool events?

Tags: c#, c++, iis, api, monitoring

I'm in the need of monitoring IIs (v6) events.

More specifically the application pool and Web Site events. Is there some API or WMI instrumentation to do this? This is not from an application perpective, but from an adminsitration perspective.

I am not interested in starting, stopping or recycling programmatically. I'm interested in monitoring the status. 
Polling is not very elegant, are there any events that I can hook into?

From managed or unmanaged code, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links might help you:

http://leandrodg.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/find-and-recycle-current-application-pool-programmatically-for-iis-6/

http://forums.iis.net/t/1148327.aspx

Comment: Look that the only way is to querying the state of the pool (your 2nd link) , unfortunately. It would have been so much nicer to subscribe to an event.

Comment: Did you find an event-based solution?

I am having the same issue here...

Thanks in advance